# linux move files inside sub folder to current directory

Tags: linux, macos, shell

hi i need a command for linux and mac os to move files from all subfolders to the current one.

I have the main folder (04) containing other folders ex. 01145032 that contains jpgs and other files.
i have to move this files in 04 folder
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```
cd 04
find . -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv '{}' . \;
```

`-mindepth 2` will make sure that only files from sub directories are found.